# Can I use an already defined function under a flask route?

Tags: python, flask

Let's say this is normal:

```
@api.route('/something', methods=['GET'])
def some_function():
    return jsonify([])
```

**Is it possible to use a function that is already defined?**

```
def some_predefined_function():
    return jsonify([])


@api.route('/something', methods=['GET'])
some_predefined_function()
```

I tried the above type of syntax but it didn't work and I"m not a python guy so I'm not sure if it silly to want to do this.

Comment: yes, you can totally do this and there are many valid reasons to do it this way. it would be easier to use the non-decorated url assignment method in an assignment like this: [Flask.add_url_rule](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to add routes in Flask, and although `@api.route` is the most elegant one, it is not the only one.

Basically a decorator is just a fancy function, you can use it inline like this:

```
api.route('/api/galleries')(some_func)
```

Internally `route` is calling [add_url_rule](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) which you can also use like this:

```
app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)
```

You can also just create a wrapper function and use it in the classical decorator way like @bren mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def some_predefined_function():
    return jsonify([])

@api.route('/something', methods=['GET'])
def something():
   return some_predefined_function()
```